# How to download file content as it gets accessed

Tags: c#, file, mp3

Would it be possible to create empty mp3 file, and then when a mp3 player tries to play such file, the mp3 file content gets download from a remote server?

Basically, I would want any ordinary mp3 player to be able to stream from a remote server as if it was playing from a local file.

If an empty file strategy would not be possible, are there other ways to let a ordinary mp3 player play a remote mp3 file?

Comment: I think you want an .m3u file. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic since there doesn't seem to be any programming aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal mp3 codec is not really designed to deal with that. It will decode around the speed of disk and once it hits the end of data, it will crash (as the rest of the file is invalid). The *concept* that data is not fully there on teh disk is not something you ever expect with filesystems. Nor do they expect the filesize to change while reading it.

That being said, it might be possible if you play the mp3 directly from a WebServer. It is fully expected that it will take time to get all the data. But in this case, it should actually be the read order to the OS that should block up. But it is equally likely the OS will fully download the file (propably into a temp directory) before it even allows the read of the 1st byte to progress.

For proper streaming you may need a specialized format. Stuff like having multiple qualities of the same data (higher resolution versions of the same image or video) placed after one another. This technique is usually called [Interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)).